# Django model queries; how to join tables on foriegnkey

Tags: python, django, django-models

models.py

```
class Person(models.Model):
    email = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    pwd = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    type = models.CharField(max_length=30)

class user_details(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    gender = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    phoneno = models.CharField(max_length=13)
    u_id = models.ForeignKey('Person', on_delete=models.CASCADE)


class User_locations(models.Model):
    country = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    state = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    district = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    locality = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    u_id = models.ForeignKey('Person', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

i want to query a Person with Person.type='A' and User_locations.locality='B'. i aslo want access name of a person with Person.name in the template.

i now use this code in views.py

```
person = Person.objects.filter(type='A', user_locations__location='B')
```

what should a add to this code to access name of the person with person.name in the html template?

Answer (score 0):

According to your code, Person does not have **name** property.

filter() returns a QuerySet which can be iterated in your template.

Pass your person variable to your template.

view:

```
persons = Person.objects.filter(type='A', user_locations__location='B')
```

template:

```
{% for person in persons %}
    {{ person.your_property }}
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: name property is stored in the user_details table. the user_deatils table and Person table is connected with foriegnkey. i want to access person.name in template by connecting user_details table with Person table.

Comment: I dont see connection between Person and user_details in your code.

Comment: u_id = models.ForeignKey('Person', on_delete=models.CASCADE)   this in user_details table